# How to Replace Laravel(5.1) $request Header in middleware And pass it to $next;

Tags: php, laravel, caching, request

I want to improve JWTAuth Token with JWTAuth.refresh to support Multiple concurrent request.

I tried this way:

1. request[1] with token[1], cache token[1]=>(count)1,  refreshToken(token[2]), cache token[2] as `LatestToken`;
2. request[2] with token[1], cache token[1]=>(count)2,  **replace** token[1] with `LatestToken`, refreshToken(token[3]), cache token[3] as `LatestToken`;
3. request[3] with token[1], cache token[1]=>(count)3, **replace** token[1] with `LatestToken`, refreshToken(token[4]), cache token[4] as `LatestToken`;
4. ...

Then met a problem that:

**The Header['Authorization'] in $request in JWTAuth middleware cann't be replaced**

the source of JWTAuth middleware as blow:

```
public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
{
    if (! $token = $this->auth->setRequest($request)->getToken()) {
        return $this->respond('tymon.jwt.absent', 'token_not_provided', 400);
    }

    try {
        $user = $this->auth->authenticate($token);
    } catch (TokenExpiredException $e) {
        return $this->respond('tymon.jwt.expired', 'token_expired', $e->getStatusCode(), [$e]);
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return $this->respond('tymon.jwt.invalid', 'token_invalid', $e->getStatusCode(), [$e]);
    }

    if (! $user) {
        return $this->respond('tymon.jwt.user_not_found', 'user_not_found', 404);
    }

    $this->events->fire('tymon.jwt.valid', $user);

    return $next($request);
}
```

I tried to find some "SET" function in [Request](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Http/Request.html%20'Request'), but there is not.

how can I deal with this?
Thank you guys any can help.

tried ways:

1. create instance of Response, and edit it then return the Response.**(not work)**
   `$response = $next($request);  $response->... ; return $response;`
2. use Facade Response set Header. **(not work)**